# pandas: Filling missing values within a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data from an experiment, and within each trial there are some single values, surrounded by `NA`'s, that I want to fill out to the entire trial:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'trial': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
    'cs_name': [np.nan, 'A1', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'B2', 
                np.nan, 'A1', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
Out[177]: 
   cs_name  trial
0      NaN      1
1       A1      1
2      NaN      1
3      NaN      1
4      NaN      2
5      NaN      2
6       B2      2
7      NaN      2
8       A1      3
9      NaN      3
10     NaN      3
11     NaN      3
```

I'm able to fill these values within the whole trial by using both `bfill()` and `ffill()`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

```
df['cs_name'] = df.groupby('trial')['cs_name'].ffill()
df['cs_name'] = df.groupby('trial')['cs_name'].bfill()
```

Expected output:

```
   cs_name  trial
0       A1      1
1       A1      1
2       A1      1
3       A1      1
4       B2      2
5       B2      2
6       B2      2
7       B2      2
8       A1      3
9       A1      3
10      A1      3
11      A1      3
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) and a [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('trial')

In [12]: g['cs_name'].transform(lambda s: s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])
Out[12]: 
0     A1
1     A1
2     A1
3     A1
4     B2
5     B2
6     B2
7     B2
8     A1
9     A1
10    A1
11    A1
Name: cs_name, dtype: object
```

*This ought to be more efficient then using ffill followed by a bfill...*

And use this to change the `cs_name` column:

```
df['cs_name'] = g['cs_name'].transform(lambda s: s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])
```

Note: I think it would be nice enhancement to have a method to grab the first non-null object in the pandas, in numpy it's [an open request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269), I don't think there is currently a method (I could be wrong!)...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid the error that appears when some groups contain only NaN you could do the following (Note that I changed the df so there are only Nan for the group having trial=1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'trial': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,1,1], 
'cs_name': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'B2', np.nan, 
'A3', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan]})

g = data.groupby('trial')

g['cs_name'].transform(lambda s: 'No values to aggregate' if 
    pd.isnull(s).all() == True else s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])

df['cs_name'] = g['cs_name'].transform(lambda s: 'No values to aggregate' if 
    pd.isnull(s).all() == True else s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])`
```

This way you input 'No Values to aggregate' (or whatever you want) when the program finds all NaN for a particular group, instead of an error.

Hope this helps :)

Federico