# Pandas Fill NA with Group Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Site':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                   'Value':[np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,2,2,3,np.nan,3]})

df

    Site    Value
0   A       NaN
1   A       1.0
2   A       NaN
3   B       NaN
4   B       2.0
5   B       2.0
6   C       3.0
7   C       NaN
8   C       3.0
```

I'd like to fill the NaN values with the most common (median or mean will do) value for the site. The desired result is:

```
    Site    Value
0   A       1.0
1   A       1.0
2   A       1.0
3   B       2.0
4   B       2.0
5   B       2.0
6   C       3.0
7   C       3.0
8   C       3.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: This is close, but no cigar:

```
df['Value']=df.groupby(['Site'])['Value'].fillna(min)
```

resulting in...

```
    Site    Value
0   A   <function amax at 0x108cf9048>
1   A   1
2   A   <function amax at 0x108cf9048>
3   B   <function amax at 0x108cf9048>
4   B   2
5   B   2
6   C   3
7   C   <function amax at 0x108cf9048>
8   C   3
```

Comment: you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `transform` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group?rq=1)

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Site').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))


  Site  Value
0    A      1
1    A      1
2    A      1
3    B      2
4    B      2
5    B      2
6    C      3
7    C      3
8    C      3
```

Comment: In the case where there is >1 column: df['Value'] = df.groupby('Site')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max()))

Comment: That's fine of course, you could also shorten to:  `df.groupby('Site').transform('mean')`