# Using a custom function Series in fillna

Tags: pandas

Can I have a custom function for fill na in Pandas?

> s.fillna(lambda r: r["SomeColumn"]**2)

I'd love to have a custom function that could take in the entire row itself.

Comment: how about using transform? like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191286/pandas-fill-na-with-group-value/36191432#36191432

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `value` argument can be a Series or DataFrame. So you could calculate the correct value ahead of time, and pass that to `.fillna`

```
fill_value = s['SomeColumn'] ** 2
s.fillna(fill_value)
```