# Replace NaN with random number

Tags: python, pandas, random, fillna

I have a dataframe of numbers such as:

```
A           B
2019-10-31  0.035333
2019-10-31  NaN
2019-11-30  -0.108532
2019-11-30  -0.030604
2019-11-30  NaN
```

I want to replace the NaN's in column B with a random gaussian number:

```
from random import seed
from random import gauss
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# generate some Gaussian value
value = gauss(0, 0.1)
```

However, if I use the following code:

```
df.fillna(gauss(0, 0.1))
```

It fills all missing values with the same random value while I want a new random value for each NaN. How should I acchieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227010/using-a-custom-function-series-in-fillna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python pandas suggests replace function.

```
df.replace('NaN', gauss(1, 0.1))
```

Output:

```
            A         B
0  2019-10-31  0.035330
1  2019-10-31 -0.036289
2  2019-11-30 -0.108532
3  2019-11-30 -0.030604
4  2019-11-30 -0.036289
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the whole array with `np.random` then fill the nan's with `loc`:

```
mask = df['B'].isna()

to_fill = np.random.normal(0,0.1, size=mask.sum())
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = to_fill
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.B.where(df.B.notna(), np.random.randn(len(df.index))*0.1 + 0)
```

Where the `B` column is not NaN, take from `np.random.randn`, else keep as is

to get

```
0    0.035333
1   -0.006504
2   -0.108532
3   -0.030604
4   -0.337191
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you just want to use `gauss`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['B'].apply(lambda x: gauss(0,.1)))
```

Output:

```
            A         B
0  2019-10-31  0.035333
1  2019-10-31 -0.143683
2  2019-11-30 -0.108532
3  2019-11-30 -0.030604
4  2019-11-30  0.054647
```