# Pandas: Fill missing values by mean in each group faster than transform

Tags: python, pandas, nan, python-3.5, mean

I need to fill missing values in a pandas DataFrame by the mean value in each group. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group) `transform` can achieve this.

However, `transform` is too slow for my purposes.

For example, take the following setting with a large DataFrame with 100 different groups and 70% `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 10000000  # DataFrame length
ngroups = 100  # Number of Groups

randgroups = np.random.randint(ngroups, size=size)  # Creation of groups
randvals = np.random.rand(size) * randgroups * 2    # Random values with mean like group number
nan_indices = np.random.permutation(range(size))    # NaN indices
nanfrac = 0.7                                       # Fraction of NaN values
nan_indices = nan_indices[:int(nanfrac*size)]       # Take fraction of NaN indices
randvals[nan_indices] = np.NaN                      # Set NaN values

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': randvals, 'group': randgroups})  # Create data frame
```

Using `transform` via

```
df.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())) # Takes too long
```

takes already more than 3 seconds on my computer. I need something by an order of magnitude faster (buying a bigger machine is not an option :-D).

So how can I fill the missing values any faster?

Comment: Is it an option to deal with the missing data before you read it into a frame?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I would prefer not to, because the real DataFrame comes from a SQL query (and is actually a few GB in size).

Comment: I'd look at doing it there then. I wouldn't be surprised if SQL was able to calculate the mean faster than what Pandas is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a NumPy approach using [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) that's pretty efficient for such bin-based summing/averaging operations -

```
ids = df.group.values                    # Extract 2 columns as two arrays
vals = df.value.values

m = np.isnan(vals)                             # Mask of NaNs
grp_sums = np.bincount(ids,np.where(m,0,vals)) # Group sums with NaNs as 0s
avg_vals = grp_sums*(1.0/np.bincount(ids,~m))        # Group averages
vals[m] = avg_vals[ids[m]]              # Set avg values into NaN positions
```

Note that this would update the `value` column.

**Runtime test**

Datasizes :

```
size = 1000000  # DataFrame length
ngroups = 10  # Number of Groups
```

Timings :

```
In [17]: %timeit df.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
1 loops, best of 3: 276 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit bincount_based(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop

In [19]: 276.0/13.6  # Speedup
Out[19]: 20.294117647058822
```

**`20x+`** speedup there!

Answer (score 3):

you're doing it wrong.  it's slow because you're using a `lambda`

```
df[['value']].fillna(df.groupby('group').transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Ah I see, maybe you should post this also as an answer to the original question, there they suggested the use of `lambda`.

Comment: Still, your solution is "only" 20% faster, but that does not come near an order of magnitude faster :-)

Comment: @SmCaterpillar With a pandas solution I doubt you can get a significant improvement on this. Most of the time is spent on calculating the mean. `df['value'].fillna(df.groupby('group', sort=False)['value'].transform('mean'))` is a little faster.

Comment: on my machine, piRSquared answer is about 6x faster.  `transform` is often way faster if you use a native function like `mean` (cythonized) rather than a lambda (not cythonized)

Comment: @SmCaterpillar  make sure you are using a recent version of pandas -- it could effect the speed of transform.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12737

Answer (score 3):

## Using a Sorted Index + `fillna()`

You are right - your code takes 3.18s to run. The code provided by @piRSquared takes 2.78s to run.

1. **Example Code**: 

       `%%timeit
       df2 = df1.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))`


   `` Output:
       1 loop, best of 3: 3.18 s per loop` ``
2. **piRSquared's improvement**:

       `%%timeit
       df[['value']].fillna(df.groupby('group').transform('mean'))`


   `Output:
       1 loop, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop`
3. **Slightly more efficient way (using a sorted index and `fillna`)**:

You can set the `group` column as the index of the dataframe, and sort it.

`df = df.set_index('group').sort_index()`

Now that you have a sorted index, the it's super cheap to access a subset of the dataframe by the group number, by using `df.loc[x,:]`

Since you need to impute by the mean for every group, you need all the unique group id's. For this example, you could use `range` (since the groups are from 0 to 99), but more generally- you can use:

`groups = np.unique(set(df.index))`

After this, you can iterate over the groups and use `fillna()` for imputation:

`%%timeit
for x in groups:
    df.loc[x,'value'] = df.loc[x,'value'].fillna(np.mean(df.loc[x,'value']))`


`Output:
    1 loop, best of 3: 231 ms per loop`

Note: `set_index`, `sort_index` and `np.unique` operations are a one time cost. To be fair to everyone, the total time (including these operations) was 2.26s on my machine, but the imputation piece took only 231 ms.