# Handing missing data of age in classification

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, classification, missing-data

I have a age feature with missing data.How can I handle this missing data.I dont want the mean of the age.Can anyone help me with this?

```
Age
22.0
38.0
26.0
35.0
35.0
NaN
45
67
```

Comment: Please give us examples and some of your code to help. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I edited.Its a classfication problem

Comment: @Anesh - It seems need [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19966018), but without data, expected output hard to know...

Comment: Its a titanic dataset from kaggle.Iam new to kaggle.Iam trying my first one.I cleaned up some of the attributes.Now Iam stuck up with this age feature.

Comment: check dupe answer with titanic dataset

Comment: Iam sorry whats dupe??

Comment: You can find some solutions in https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/handling-missing-values