# Fill one column of last item in group with another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of assignments per case. I'm trying to fill the last `unassigned` from each case with the `case_closed` date.

```
case_nb   attorney      cas_closed_date assigned    last_event
1         A             2015-07-02      2015-07-02  2015-07-02
2         B             2015-09-10      2015-09-10  2015-09-10
3         C             2016-03-24      2016-03-24  2016-03-24
4         D             2018-06-07      2013-10-21  2014-02-06
4         C             2018-06-07      2013-09-13  2013-09-13
4         F             2018-06-07      2018-03-31  2018-04-05
```

(For replication:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'assigned': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10', 2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2013-10-21', 4: '2013-09-13', 5: '2018-03-31'},
                    'attorney': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'C', 5: 'F'},
                    'cas_closed_date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10', 2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2018-06-07', 4: '2018-06-07', 5: '2018-06-07'},
                    'case_nb': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4},
                    'last_event': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10', 2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2014-02-06', 4: '2013-09-13', 5: '2018-04-05'}}
```

)

My dataset includes the case number, attorney assigned, the case closed date, the date the attorney was assigned, and the last event the attorney appeared on. For the above example, I'd want the last line to be

```
4         F             2018-06-07      2018-03-31  2018-06-07
```

I've seen a few ways of filling in NAs based on data in the same column, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group?noredirect=1&lq=1). But these ways use `transform`, which I can't get to use multiple columns.

What I have so far works with `apply`, but not `transform`:

```
def fixdate(gp):
    last_unasgn = gp.iloc[-1]['last_event']
    if gp.iloc[-1]['cas_closed_date'] > last_unasgn:
        return gp.iloc[-1]['cas_closed_date']
    else:
       return last_unasgn

asmt.groupby('evt_file_number').apply(lambda x: fixdate(x))
> 4  2018-06-07
```

Is there a way to use `transform`? If not, what's the best way to use that aggregate data to fill in my original dataset?

Comment: Hi, please share your `df.to_dict()` so it will be easier to help you. It is not clear to me what do you want to obtain: do you want to write the date the case is closed on last_event? Or do you want to do so just for the last attorney who received the case?

Comment: @user32185 `to_dict` posted. The final `last_event` for a group should be the `cas_closed_date` for that group (which is the second option you wrote, I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case the same `case_nb` is never assigned on the same day to two different attorney you can try this solution.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'assigned': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10',
                                2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2013-10-21', 4: '2013-09-13',
                                5: '2018-03-31'},
                    'attorney': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'C', 5: 'F'},
                    'cas_closed_date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10',
                                        2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2018-06-07', 4: '2018-06-07',
                                        5: '2018-06-07'},
                    'case_nb': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4},
                    'last_event': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-07-02'), 1: '2015-09-10',
                                   2: '2016-03-24', 3: '2014-02-06', 4: '2013-09-13',
                                   5: '2018-04-05'}})

out = df.groupby("case_nb")["assigned"].max().reset_index()
out["last"] = True
df = pd.merge(df, out, how="left", on= ["case_nb", "assigned"])
df["last_event"] = np.where(df["last"] == True, df["cas_closed_date"], df["last_event"])
del df["last"], out
```

Probably there is a more elegant solution but at least this is vectorial (see `np.where`) and don't use `apply`. [pandas performaces](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/enhancingperf.html).

**EDIT** In case you want to use `transform` there is this option which seems to me to be the fastest solution.

```
df["last_assigned"] = df.groupby("case_nb")["assigned"].transform("max")
df["last_event"] = np.where(df["assigned"]==df["last_assigned"], 
                            df["cas_closed_date"],
                            df["last_event"])
del df["last_assigned"]
```

Comment: With `%%timeit%%, your `np.where` solution took `1.45 ms ± 37.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`, and my `loc` solution took `2.14 ms ± 72.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`. So I would say `np.where` is the clear winner.

Comment: @RCA Did you try on your real case `df`?

Answer (score 1):

The `.transform` operation passes all columns for each group as a one dimensional Series to the function, while the `.apply` operation passes all columns for each group as a DataFrame to the function. So, `.transform` works on one Series (or column) at a time and `.apply` works for an entire DataFrame (or all columns). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I knew vaguely that's what it was doing, but your answer helped me think through how to create a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a combination of `transform` and just plain indexing.

```
df = df.sort_values(['case_nb', 'last_event'])
df['last_unassigned'] = df.groupby('case_nb')['last_event'].transform('last')
df.loc[(df['last_event'] == df['last_unassigned'])
        & (df['last_unassigned'] != df['cas_closed_date']), 'last_event'] = df['cas_closed_date']
```

Comment: do you mind to test this solution vs my last one with your df to see which one is faster on the real case?
Then I think this condition `df['last_unassigned'] != df['cas_closed_date']` is redundant. I mean in case these values are the same it doesn't harm update `df["last_event"]` with itself.