# TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame" in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am breaking on subjected issue. I am not sure why is it breaking and what are the amendments required.

Code:

```
table = df.pivot_table(values='LoanAmount', index='Self_Employed' ,columns='Education', aggfunc=np.median)

def fage(x):
    return table.loc[x['Self_Employed'],x['Education']]

#Replacing missing values

df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage,axis=1),inplace =True)
```

Output:

[15]: df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage,axis=1),inplace =True)

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "<ipython-input-15-dadf94659135>", line 1, in <module>
    df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage,axis=1),inplace =True)

  File "/home/aryabhatta/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3422, in fillna
    **kwargs)

  File "/home/aryabhatta/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5400, in fillna
    '"{0}"'.format(type(value).__name__))

TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame"
```

Comment: Please do include the *full traceback* so we can identify where the problem arose. The last line here doesn't give us that context.

Comment: Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19966018/2901002) ?

Comment: *Pivot_table* is of little importance here.
Please provide the content of *table* (at least a representative fragment)
and what is the expected result (for this fragment).

Comment: there should not be any sort of error. Ya, you can exclude it for time being.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please make sure that

I hope you didn't execute this line before for filling missing values of LoanAmount

```
df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

The error is the LoanAmount is already filled with other values and there are no missing values in it.so it throws the error.

Replacing missing values:

```
df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage,axis=1),inplace =True
```

Before executing above code make sure `LoanAmount` has missing values execute below command to check.

```
df.apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()),axis=0)
```

The above command will shows the missing count of `LoanAmount`. If you have missing values then only you can replace with either fage or mean.