# Impute Column Values Based on Other Column's Conditions - Python Pandastic Way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
    cat1     cat2   cat3 day
0   10       25     12   Monday 
1   11       22     14   Tuesday
2   12       30     15   Wednesday
3   10       36     12   Thursday
4   15       38     14   Friday
5   NaN      42     13   Monday
6   11       32     10   Tuesday
7   15       30     12   Wednesday
8   13       28     09   Thursday
9   10       29     10   Friday
10  12       30     16   Monday
```

Now I want to replace the `NaN` value with the mean of `cat1` column that is filtered by `Monday` from `day` column. My output would be,

```
        cat1     cat2   cat3 day
    0   10       25     12   Monday 
    1   11       22     14   Tuesday
    2   12       30     15   Wednesday
    3   10       36     12   Thursday
    4   15       38     14   Friday
    5   11       42     13   Monday
    6   11       32     10   Tuesday
    7   15       30     12   Wednesday
    8   13       28     09   Thursday
    9   10       29     10   Friday
    10  12       30     16   Monday
```

I was thinking of doing this filtering my dataframe by `day` column's `Monday` value, replace `NaN` with `.mean()` function and then append it back to the dataframe. For example,

```
monday_df = df[df['day'] == 'Monday']
mean_val  = monday_df['cat1'].mean()
monday_df['cat1']= Monday_df['cat1'].fillna(mean_val)
```

After this, append it back to the original `df`. But this seems to be lot of coding, is there a `pandastic` way (possibly one liner) to do this so I get my desired output?

Comment: `df.fillna(df.groupby('day').transform('mean'))`

Comment: `df['cat1'].fillna(df.loc[df['day']=='Monday']['cat1'].mean())` ?

Comment: Wrong dup, this is `mean`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group

Comment: @harvpan this is giving me a column of values :( I need a whole `df` as output.

Comment: @Erfan your code is missing a `]` and also just returning a column of values. But I need a whole dataframe as output

Comment: @user9431057 that is your imput-ed `cat1`. :( `df['cat1']=df['cat1'].fillna(df.loc[df['day']=='Monday']['cat1'].mean())` updates your `df`.

Comment: @Erfan Understood, thank you :) Still your does not work.