# How to iterate over a DataFrame for a selected coulmn using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, kaggle

suppose i have a sample code like this

```
_d=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,np.nan,6],[np.nan,np.nan,8]],columns=['x','y','z'])
```

now, i have a function which checks for the value and assigns a desired value according to the scenerio

```
def handling_nan(_d):
    if _d['x']==1.0:
        return 100
    else:
        return _d
```

when i use this, in my below code,

```
_result=_d.apply(lambda x:handling_nan(x))
_result
```

i am getting error

> KeyError: ('x', 'occurred at index x')

**UPDATE A :**

well, in short, i am using the dataset from kaggle.com ie. **Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster** and in that dataset, i want to introduce a new column with condition something like this.

> if male and the age is NaN then insert the mean() age of men instead of NaN and if
>   female and the age is NaN, then insert the mean() of the total female age instead of NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyError` is encountered in the function since `apply()` method on a dataframe assumes `axis=0`. This means that the function will be applied on every column and not every row. To remove this error, the `apply()` call needs to be replaced as:

```
_result=_d.apply(lambda x:handling_nan(x), axis=1)
```

---

Looking at the edit, the question is to replace `NaNs` with grouped means in the dataset.

This can be done using `fillna()` and `transform()` method as following:

```py
l = [["M", 30], ["M", 45], ["M", None], ["F", 76], ["F", 23], ["F", None]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["sex", "age"])
df['age'] = df['age'].fillna(df.groupby("sex")['age'].transform('mean'))
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group) answer has other alternative solutions.

Hope this helps.