# How to fill na based on other value in the same group by Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

I want to fill NA in my dataset based on the value from the other row in the same group.

The data looks like this.

```
 group_id, start_time, end_time  
    1, NA, 20000
    1, 40000, 20000
    1, 30000, NA
    2, NA, 35000
    2, 45000, 22000
    2, 50000,21000
    2, 45000, NA
```

I want to get this result:

```
 group_id, start_time, end_time  
        1, 30000, 20000
        1, 40000, 20000
        1, 30000, 20000
        2, 45000, 35000
        2, 45000, 22000
        2, 50000,21000
        2, 45000, 35000
```

So the first and last value on each group are same  on both start_time, and end_time .

Comment: So you want to fill it in with the group minimum for start_time and the group maximum for end_time?

Comment: So the value of start_time and end_time in both first and last row of group are the same. As can be seen that the first NA in group _id 1 is 30000 , which is based on the third row.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will be useful for you and the community. Tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @FrancescoLucianò. Thanks for your reminder. Noted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `fillna`, `groupby`, `tranform` and the `first` or `last` aggregation functions, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339320/1011724)

```
df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].fillna(df.groupby('group_id')['start_time'].transform('last'))
df['end_time'] = df['end_time'].fillna(df.groupby('group_id')['end_time'].transform('first'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select a value from one column (of the default values) if the condition for that row (is.na) matches, else select values from some other column (in this case, the same column).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = """
group_id,start_time,end_time
1,NA,20000
1,40000,20000
1,30000,NA
2,NA,35000
2,45000,22000
2,50000,21000
2,45000,NA
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(TESTDATA), sep=",") # parse your sample data
```

In this case, the default values you asked for are the first/last of each group, so we will need to construct columns for these:

```
start_time_last = df.groupby("group_id")["start_time"].last()
end_time_first = df.groupby("group_id")["end_time"].first()
merged = df.join(start_time_last, on='group_id', how='left', rsuffix='_last').join(end_time_first, on='group_id', how='left', rsuffix='_first')
```

Now we can use `np.where` to fill in the `na` values:

```
merged["start_time"] = np.where(pd.isna(merged["start_time"]), merged["start_time_last"], merged["start_time"])
merged["end_time"] = np.where(pd.isna(merged["end_time"]), merged["end_time_first"], merged["end_time"])
print(merged)
```

Gives:

```
   group_id  start_time  end_time  start_time_last  end_time_first
0         1     30000.0   20000.0          30000.0         20000.0
1         1     40000.0   20000.0          30000.0         20000.0
2         1     30000.0   20000.0          30000.0         20000.0
3         2     45000.0   35000.0          45000.0         35000.0
4         2     45000.0   22000.0          45000.0         35000.0
5         2     50000.0   21000.0          45000.0         35000.0
6         2     45000.0   35000.0          45000.0         35000.0
```

Comment: You can use `transform` to avoid needing to do all that joining. Once you have that, you can just use fillna to fill in the values.

Comment: @Dan Didn't notice your answer until after I posted, but your solution using `transform` is much more elegant!

Answer (score -1):

You could make a loop to iterate over that and if the value is NA change it