# How to fillna to non-integer with mean for that group, and also replace all-NaN groups with 0

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I want to do a special `fillna()` on the following data set, as follows:

```
name,spend,received
A,1012,1200
A,?,1500
B,1300,?
B,2000,2500
B,?,?
C,?,?
C,?,?
```

- In this dataset `?` means any `non-integer value` like `na` or `???`
- A `spend` value of `?` of A,B,C rows has to be replaced with the mean of that group, i.e. `?` should be replaced with `np.mean(A),np.mean(B),np.mean(C)`
- for `C` there are no other values so it has to be `0`

We can't directly apply `fillna(np.mean)` in this case.

Comment: Please include the desired result.

Comment: Also are the number strings or ints?

Comment: Related (but not dupe) answer: [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group/59139984#59139984)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
df = df.replace("?", np.NaN)
df.spend = pd.to_numeric(df.spend)
df.recieved = pd.to_numeric(df.recieved)
df.loc[df.spend.isna(), "spend"] = df.groupby("name").transform("mean").loc[df.spend.isna(), "spend"]
df["spend"] = df.spend.fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
  name   spend  recieved
0    A  1012.0    1200.0
1    A  1012.0    1500.0
2    B  1300.0       NaN
3    B  2000.0    2500.0
4    B  1650.0       NaN
5    C     0.0       NaN
6    C     0.0       NaN
```

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. use `pd.read_csv(..., na_values='?')` to replace your NaNs at read-time
2. we'll adapt the [basic answer on replacing NaNs within a group with its mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139984/202229)
3. your twist is that all-NaN groups will result in NaN mean, which should then itself be fillna() replaced with 0

So the key line is:

```
df['spend'] = df.groupby('name')['spend'].apply(lambda s: s.fillna(s.mean())).fillna(0)
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dat = """name,spend,received
A,1012,1200
A,?,1500
B,1300,?
B,2000,2500
B,?,?
C,?,?
C,?,?"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), na_values='?')

  name   spend  received
0    A  1012.0    1200.0
1    A     NaN    1500.0
2    B  1300.0       NaN
3    B  2000.0    2500.0
4    B     NaN       NaN
5    C     NaN       NaN
6    C     NaN       NaN

df['spend'] = df.groupby('name')['spend'].apply(lambda s: s.fillna(s.mean())).fillna(0)

  name   spend  received
0    A  1012.0    1200.0
1    A  1012.0    1500.0
2    B  1300.0       NaN
3    B  2000.0    2500.0
4    B  1650.0       NaN
5    C     0.0       NaN
6    C     0.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ? could also be strings

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3 + ['C'] * 3
data = np.random.random_sample((9,2))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=data[::], columns=['spend', 'recieved'])
df.index.name = 'name'

df.iloc[2, 1] = np.nan
df.iloc[1, 0] = 'ABCD'
df.iloc[4:6, 0] = np.nan
```

df

```
name    spend       recieved    
A       0.197366    0.467532
A       ABCD        0.256184
A       0.559562    NaN
B       0.59835     0.415382
B       NaN         0.163827
B       NaN         0.759888
C       0.897332    0.025344
C       0.782683    0.428465
C       0.201591    0.601339
```

Then

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df['spend'] = df['spend'].groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()).fillna(0))
df['recieved'] = df['recieved'].groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()).fillna(0))
```

Which yields:

```
name spend      recieved        
A    0.197366   0.467532
A    0.378464   0.256184
A    0.559562   0.361858
B    0.598350   0.415382
B    0.598350   0.163827
B    0.598350   0.759888
C    0.897332   0.025344
C    0.782683   0.428465
C    0.201591   0.601339
```