# Conditional NaN filling not changing column or making all None

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan, isnullorempty

I have a df with a column, Critic_Score, that has NaN values. I am trying to replace them with the average of the Critic Scores from the same platform. This question has been asked on stack overflow several times and I used 4 suggestions that did not give me the desired output. Please tell me how to fix this.

This is a subset of the df:

```
x[['Platform','Critic_Score']].head()

Platform    Critic_Score
0   wii 76.0
1   nes NaN
2   wii 82.0
3   wii 80.0
4   gb  NaN
```

More information on the original df:

```
x.head().to_dict('list')
{'Name': ['wii sports',
  'super mario bros.',
  'mario kart wii',
  'wii sports resort',
  'pokemon red/pokemon blue'],
 'Platform': ['wii', 'nes', 'wii', 'wii', 'gb'],
 'Year_of_Release': [2006.0, 1985.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 1996.0],
 'Genre': ['sports', 'platform', 'racing', 'sports', 'role-playing'],
 'NA_sales': [41.36, 29.08, 15.68, 15.61, 11.27],
 'EU_sales': [28.96, 3.58, 12.76, 10.93, 8.89],
 'JP_sales': [3.77, 6.81, 3.79, 3.28, 10.22],
 'Other_sales': [8.45, 0.77, 3.29, 2.95, 1.0],
 'Critic_Score': [76.0, nan, 82.0, 80.0, nan],
 'User_Score': ['8', nan, '8.3', '8', nan],
 'Rating': ['E', nan, 'E', 'E', nan]}
```

These are the statements I tried followed by their output:

1.

```
x['Critic_Score'] = x['Critic_Score'].fillna(x.groupby('Platform')['Critic_Score'].transform('mean'), inplace = True)

0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
Name: Critic_Score, dtype: object
```

2. 

```
x.loc[x.Critic_Score.isnull(), 'Critic_Score'] = x.groupby('Platform').Critic_Score.transform('mean')
#no change in column
0    76.0
1     NaN
2    82.0
3    80.0
4     NaN
```

3. 

```
x['Critic_Score'] = x.groupby('Platform')['Critic_Score']\
    .transform(lambda y: y.fillna(y.mean()))
#no change in column
0    76.0
1     NaN
2    82.0
3    80.0
4     NaN
Name: Critic_Score, dtype: float64
```

4. 

```
x['Critic_Score']=x.groupby('Platform')['Critic_Score'].apply(lambda y:y.fillna(y.mean()))
​
x['Critic_Score'].head()
​

Out[73]:
0    76.0
1     NaN
2    82.0
3    80.0
4     NaN
Name: Critic_Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Got it. Sorry. 
This is what I have: 
print(x.head())
x = x.update(x.groupby('Platform').transform('mean'))

x['Critic_Score'].head()

Comment: 0    76.0
1     NaN
2    82.0
3    80.0
4     NaN
Name: Critic_Score, dtype: float64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-efba0c6425a8> in <module>
     23 x = x.update(x.groupby('Platform').transform('mean'))
     24 
---> 25 x['Critic_Score'].head()
     26 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Turns out this has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966142/6692898

Comment: So I tried that method, and for some reason it just replaced the values of the 'Critic_Score' with the values of the Year_Released (it was the column next to critic_score in the actual data_frame)

Comment: @RichieV, I incorporated your suggestion into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.update(
    x.groupby('Platform').Critic_Score.transform('mean'),
    overwrite=False)
```

- First you create a new df with the same number of rows but with the platform average on every row.
- Then use that to update the original

Bear in mind your sample has only one row of `nes` and another of `gb`, both with `nan` score, so there is nothing to be averaged

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. I tried this method and got this: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: I made sure it is not None before passing into the statement you provided, this is what I got: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That did not change anything :(

Comment: No, it had no exception, it just returned the same column without replacing the NaN

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it exactly but it does not replace the NaN. I tried setting overwrite to true and it changed every value except the NaN

Comment: Yes I do, but there are instances where a platform has at least one score and yet it is showing as NaN

Comment: It seems like all such instances are doing that