# Pandas: Fill gaps in a series with mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given df

`df = pd.DataFrame({'distance': [0,1,2,np.nan,3,4,5,np.nan,np.nan,6]})`

```
   distance
0       0.0
1       1.0
2       2.0
3       NaN
4       3.0
5       4.0
6       5.0
7       NaN
8       NaN
9       6.0
```

I want to replace the nans with the inbetween mean

Expected output:

```
   distance
0       0.0
1       1.0
2       2.0
3       2.5
4       3.0
5       4.0
6       5.0
7       5.5
8       5.5
9       6.0
```

I have seen [this_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group) but it's for a grouping which isn't my case and I couldn't find anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want [`df.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) you can compute the mean of the surrounding values manually with [`df.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and [`df.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
(df.ffill() + df.bfill()) / 2
```

Out:

```
   distance
0       0.0
1       1.0
2       2.0
3       2.5
4       3.0
5       4.0
6       5.0
7       5.5
8       5.5
9       6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using linear interpolation?

```
print(df.distance.interpolate())

0    0.000000
1    1.000000
2    2.000000
3    2.500000
4    3.000000
5    4.000000
6    5.000000
7    5.333333
8    5.666667
9    6.000000
Name: distance, dtype: float64
```