# Pandas transform on a object column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, transform

I have gone through this thread - [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group)
To impute mean of the group by using pandas transform function.
However the column that i am referring to has a string and which is different ex: Car Model missing mileage/engine power etc...
Find attached sample data, let me know how to impute the values[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa8rO.jpg)

Comment: Can you post an example of your code?

Comment: I dont have code, i am trying to find how to apply transform where the column names are different... I have attached the snapshot of the data

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/vehicle-dataset-from-cardekho/Car details 
v3.csv')

#mileage filled with mean mileage

df['mileage'] = df['mileage'].str.split().str[0].astype(float)
df['mileage'].fillna(df.mileage.mean(), inplace = True)

#engine filled with mean engine

df['engine'].fillna(df.engine.mean(), inplace = True)

#max_power, torque, seats filled with most frequent value

df['max_power'].fillna(df.max_power.value_counts().index[0], inplace = 
True)
df['torque'].fillna(df.torque.value_counts().index[0], inplace = True)
df['seats'].fillna(df.seats.value_counts().index[0], inplace = True)
```

Comment: I am asking how to impute missing mileage/engine/bhp of a bmw 520d series car based on bmw 520 series model cars.

Comment: If you can post the specific pandas dataframe and problem I could help you out, without it I am making assumptions about the data. The more specific the better!

Comment: Hi, This is the data set i am using - https://www.kaggle.com/nehalbirla/vehicle-dataset-from-cardekho?select=Car+details+v3.csv
There are missing values in mileage, engine, max_power variables. How do i impute the missing variables?