# Python: how to fill up the mean value referencing from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by, fillna

I have a housing dataframe:

[image]

where there are missing values in the Price column. I wish to fill the missing values by the mean price in the respective suburb.

This is my code for filling up the mean price by the same column:

```py
all_housing_df['Price'].fillna(all_housing_df['Price'].mean())
```

How to fill in the mean price by the respective suburb?

Comment: please post your code as a text instead of image/picture so that we can reproduce your dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform` to fill missing values with the full list after grouping by Suburb

```
all_housing_df["Price"].fillna(all_housing_df.groupby("Suburb")["Price"].transform("mean"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `Suburb`, get the mean `Price` and save this as a dictionary to conditionally replace null values.

```py
# Create dictionary for NaN values
nan_dict = all_housing_df.groupby('Suburb')['Price'].mean().to_dict()

# Replace NaN with dictionary
all_housing_df['Price'].fillna(all_housing_df['Suburb'].map(nan_dict))
```