# Filling missing values of test from groupby mean of training set

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have two dataframes, `train` and `test`. The `test` set has missing values on a column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,7],[0,7],[1,3],[1,5],[1,2],[1,2]]
test = [[0,0],[0,np.nan],[1,0],[1,np.nan]]

train = pd.DataFrame(train, columns = ['A','B'])
test = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['A','B'])
```

The test set has two missing values on column `B`. If the groupby column is `A`

- If the imputing strategy is `mode`, then the missing values should be imputed with `7` and `2`.
- If the imputing strategy is `mean`, then the missing values should be `(1+2+3+7+7)/5 = 4` and `(3+5+2+2)/4 = 3`.

What is a good way to do this?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group) is related, but uses only one dataframe instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
from statistics import mode

test_mode = test.set_index('A').fillna(train.groupby('A').agg(mode)).reset_index()
test_mean = test.set_index('A').fillna(train.groupby('A').mean()).reset_index()
```

If you want a function:

```
from statistics import mode

def evaluate_nan(strategy= 'mean'):
    return test.set_index('A').fillna(train.groupby('A').agg(strategy)).reset_index()

test_mean = evaluate_nan()
test_mode = evaluate_nan(strategy = mode)
```