# How can I replace null values in a dataframe with generated groupby values in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For example, if I got a data frame for high school students with "Age" and "Grade" columns. I would like to replace all null values in "Age" column with the average age for each Grade.

Comment: `df["Age"].fillna(df["Age"].mean())`

Comment: @MoSai : Sample input and expected output would help here. May be it is already answered by Jyr's comment above!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: filling missing values by mean in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group)