# Adding a summarised column back into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

as part of some data cleansing, i want to add the mean of a variable back into a dataframe to use if the variable is missing for a particular observation. so i've calculated my averages as follows

```
avg=all_data2.groupby("portfolio")"[sales"].mean().reset_index(name="sales_mean")
```

now I wanted to add that back into my original dataframe using a left join, but it doesnt appear to be working. what format is my avg now? I thought it would be a dataframe but is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

This is probably the most succinct way to do it:

```py
all_data2.sales = all_data2.sales.fillna(all_data2.groupby('portfolio').sales.transform('mean'))
```

This is another way to do it:

```py
all_data2['sales'] = all_data2[['portfolio', 'sales']].groupby('portfolio').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Output:

```
   portfolio  sales
0          1   10.0
1          1   20.0
2          2   30.0
3          2   40.0
4          3   50.0
5          3   60.0
6          3    NaN
   portfolio  sales
0          1   10.0
1          1   20.0
2          2   30.0
3          2   40.0
4          3   50.0
5          3   60.0
6          3   55.0
```

To answer your the part of your question that reads "[what format is my avg now? I thought it would be a dataframe but is it something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143059/adding-a-summarised-column-back-into-a-dataframe-in-python/72145080#72145080)", `avg` is indeed a dataframe but using it may not be the most direct way to update missing data in the original dataframe. The dataframe `avg` looks like this for the sample input data above:

```
   portfolio  sales_mean
0          1        15.0
1          2        35.0
2          3        55.0
```

A related SO question that you may find helpful is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group).

Comment: @Denis Mclaughlin Do you need additional help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new column, you can use this code:

```
df['sales_mean']=df[['sales_1','sales_2']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: does that work if I want the mean split by a different categorical variable?