# Impute date value from minimum date in other column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like,

| Division | Employee | Date of Join | Obs Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DV1 | Emp1 | 01/01/1972 | 10/10/1996 |
| Dv2 | Emp1 | 25/10/1989 | 24/05/1999 |
| Dv1 | Emp2 | Null | 02/02/1995 |
| DV1 | Emp2 | Null | 05/02/1995 |
| Dv2 | Emp2 | 10/10/2000 | 20/05/2001 |

I want to get the minimum **Obs Date** for each employee, whose **date of join** is null. And replace it.
Please note that the **Employee code** is duplicated across divisions. However, both **Division** and **Employee** compositely represent the same employee.

Output needs to be,

| Division | Employee | Date of Join | Obs Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DV1 | Emp1 | 01/01/1972 | 10/10/1996 |
| Dv2 | Emp1 | 25/10/1989 | 24/05/1999 |
| Dv1 | Emp2 | **02/02/1995** | 02/02/1995 |
| DV1 | Emp2 | **02/02/1995** | 05/02/1995 |
| Dv2 | Emp2 | 10/10/2000 | 20/05/2001 |

How can I do this in Python? I'm open to using the Pandas library if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming "Dv1" and "DV1" in your table are **the same value** (else, the problem doesn't make sense to me). If this is the case, you would have to do some cleaning before you apply the following solution. I.E: `df['Division'] = df['Division'].str.lower()`. If you want you could restore the previous values afterward.

You can use:

```
df['Date of Join'] = df['Date of Join'].fillna(df.groupby(['Division','Employee'])['Obs Date'].transform("min"))
```

Output:

|  | Division | Employee | Date of Join | Obs Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | DV1 | Emp1 | 01/01/1972 | 10/10/1996 |
| 1 | Dv2 | Emp1 | 25/10/1989 | 24/05/1999 |
| 2 | DV1 | Emp2 | **02/02/1995** | 02/02/1995 |
| 3 | DV1 | Emp2 | **02/02/1995** | 05/02/1995 |
| 4 | Dv2 | Emp2 | 10/10/2000 | 20/05/2001 |

What this does is:

- `df['Date of Join']`: Assign all values of the column.
- `df['Date of Join'].fillna()`: Get values of the column, but replace the `Null` values.
- `df.groupby(['Division','Employee'])['Obs Date']`: Group by the keys and lets focus in the `Obs Date` column of each group.
- `transform("min")`: From where I found a hint for this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339320/1311269):

> The `groupby` + `transform` syntax maps the groupwise mean to the index of the original dataframe.