# How do I prevent `ffill` to completely drop my grouping column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How do I prevent the `.ffill()` method to drop my grouping variable without overwriting my `val` column?

That is, not doing: `samp_df['val'] = samp_df.groupby('ID').ffill()`

Further, why does `.groupby` behaves this way and not the same way it does with `.mean()`, moving my grouping variable to the index?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

samp_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                        'val': [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan]})

print(samp_df.groupby('ID').mean())

    val
ID     
A   1.5
B   3.5

print(samp_df.groupby('ID').ffill())

   val
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  4.0
5  4.0
```

Comment: mean is agg function ffill is not ~ to get the same output , do as_index=False within groupby

Comment: that does not work, if you do as_index=False it behaves the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: Filling missing values within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265930/pandas-filling-missing-values-within-a-group)