# Python pandas replace NaN values of one column(A) by mode (of same column -A) with respect to another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

Here is the dataframe with some `NaN` values,

```
data = {'Number':[100,None,None,200,150,None,100,120,110,210,120],
    'Street':['A','B','C','D','C','D','A','B','B','D','B']}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

*Output:*

```
    Number  Street
0   100.0   A
1   NaN     B
2   NaN     C
3   200.0   D
4   150.0   C
5   NaN     D
6   100.0   A
7   120.0   B
8   110.0   B
9   210.0   D
10  120.0   B
```

I want to replace the `NaN` values of the column *'Number'* by the mode of the same column with respect to the column *'Street'*.

*The output I need is:*

```
    Number  Street
0   100       A
1   120       B
2   150       C
3   200       D
4   150       C
5   200       D
6   100       A
7   120       B
8   110       B
9   210       D
10  120       B
```

*Explanation:*

For example, consider row 1 which has a `NaN` value in the column *Number* and the corresponding *Street* is `B` . The `NaN` value of *Number* should be replaced by `120.0` which is the mode of the column *Number* with respect to *Street*. Because, the other values for the column *Number* for  *Street* `B` are  `120.0, 110.0` and `120.0` (look at row nos 7,8,10), and the mode for this is `120.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for return first `mode` and replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]
df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(df.groupby('Street')['Number'].transform(f))
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: fillna(x.mode().iat[0])
df['Number'] = df.groupby('Street')['Number'].transform(f)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Number Street
0    100.0      A
1    120.0      B
2    150.0      C
3    200.0      D
4    150.0      C
5    200.0      D
6    100.0      A
7    120.0      B
8    110.0      B
9    210.0      D
10   120.0      B
```

Here is possible error if some group has only `NaN/None`s:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Then solution is:

```
data = {'Number':[None,None,None,200,150,None,None,120,110,210,120],
    'Street':['A','B','C','D','C','D','A','B','B','D','B']}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
    Number Street
0      NaN      A
1      NaN      B
2      NaN      C
3    200.0      D
4    150.0      C
5      NaN      D
6      NaN      A
7    120.0      B
8    110.0      B
9    210.0      D
10   120.0      B

f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0] if x.notna().any() else np.nan
df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(df.groupby('Street')['Number'].transform(f))
print (df)
    Number Street
0      NaN      A
1    120.0      B
2    150.0      C
3    200.0      D
4    150.0      C
5    200.0      D
6      NaN      A
7    120.0      B
8    110.0      B
9    210.0      D
10   120.0      B
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit simpler, as `mode` returns an array So, you can impute Nan values within `Number` by grabbing the first element of it to get the results.

### Solution 1:

```
>>> df['Number'] = df.groupby('Street')['Number'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
    # df['Number'] = df.groupby('Street').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
>>> df
    Number Street
0    100.0      A
1    120.0      B
2    150.0      C
3    200.0      D
4    150.0      C
5    200.0      D
6    100.0      A
7    120.0      B
8    110.0      B
9    210.0      D
10   120.0      B
```

### Solution 2:

You can see the another [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265930/pandas-filling-missing-values-within-a-group) based on the `loc` and [first_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html)

```
df['Number'] = df.groupby('Street')['Number'].transform(lambda s: s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])
```

OR

```
df.assign(Number=df.groupby(['Street']).Number.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])))

  or

df.assign(Number=df.groupby(['Street']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0])))
```

Comment: ya, my second solution `transform` changed to `apply`

Comment: @jezrael, true..  you are champ man. +1 for the same.